# ES match_phrase_prefix with highlight, only highlight matching prefixes, not the entire word

Tags: elasticsearch

I am currently planning to use ES as a search engine to provide technical support for my service. I hope it can search for things through user input as a prefix and use highlighting function, but I cannot only highlight the prefix instead of the entire word.

I already read the official docs and searched for stackoverflow, still can't resolve it.

```
# never mind the `...`
input: e
real output: ...<em>end</em>...
expected output: ...<em>e</em>nd...
```

My es `/_search` json like this:

```json
GET /<index>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_phrase_prefix": {
          "title": "e"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "title": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to highlight characters within words using elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59718568/how-to-highlight-characters-within-words-using-elasticsearch)